# Dual booting windows 8/Ubuntu 12.04.2, GRUB doesn't appear and Ubuntu never boots

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8, acer

I got a new ACER predator AG3620-UR308 which came with windows 8 and I wanted to run ubuntu 12.04.2 on it as a dual boot machine. The box came with 2TB HDD. So I made 4 partitions with a raw partition just after the windows installation partition.

I created a swap area and finished the installation. GRUB was installed on the only drive there which is `/dev/sda`.

After reboot, GRUB doesn't even come up. It always boots Windows 8. I repeated installation process twice and got the same result. I disabled `secure boot` from the BIOS and enabled `CSM` (don't even know what it means) according to [Acer custhelp site](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27071/~/how-to-enable-or-disable-secure-boot) . I boot from USB and got this:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't  support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes 
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x8c361cb5

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdb: 8178 MB, 8178892800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 994 cylinders, total 15974400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0006a87e

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    15972351     7985152    b  W95 FAT32
```

Can anybody shed some light? thank you in advance

**EDIT**
I just did another trial with 13.04 this time and still no luck.

```
bios: secure-boot: disabled   
enable CSM : always
```

- Deleted previous Ubuntu partition and swap area partition.now having free space
- Used usb installer to prepare usb with ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso
- rebooted : liveusb didnt detect windows 8, used something else
- created partition ext4 for `/`
- created partition for swap-area
- default grub path is `/dev/sda` and clicked install

Acer always boots into windows.

**NEW EDIT**

After following the boot-repair suggestion installed on the liveUSB, I can now see grub but can't log into windows anymore as it's not in the list. The boot-repair also completed with an error, i guess logged on [pastin.ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5838337/)

How my drive is organized

[image: gparted shot]

Comment: Windows 8 pre installed? Turned off secure boot? This can help - http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: Hello, i've read it. I did disable secure boot before the second installation. From within windows linux partition has already be created.Besides i use ubuntu 12.04.2 that should actually work. But for some reason it doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) in Ubuntu.

---

### Installing Boot Repair

1. Open the Terminal, then type:

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
2. Press Enter.
3. Then type:

   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
4. Press Enter

### Using Boot Repair

Search for Boot Repair in the dash and launch it. Then click the "Recommended Repair" button and wait until it's finished.

---

Reboot. It should work now, although your GRUB is probably littered with useless entries.

Comment: where exactly this is done? i can't boot in ubuntu so i assume this is done with liveUSB or liveCD.Are we on the same page?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my post with `NEW EDIT`. kindly see into it , thanks

Comment: What was the error that boot repair gave?

Comment: sorry i thought i pasted it http://paste.ubuntu.com/5838337/

Comment: @blacksensei Sorry I didn't see it. Hm...

Comment: I run it again and it's solved. Thanks to who ever worked on `boot-repair` and thanks to @com.BOY

Comment: @blacksensei If this answer solved your question, please click the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write GRUB manually. Boot from CD and run this command:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

In some cases you have to run more commands. Let's assume that you have Windows partition on /dev/sda1, swap on /dev/sda5, /boot on /dev/sda6 and Ubuntu root on /dev/sda7. Then you have to run these commands:

```
sudo su
mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
cd /mnt
mount /dev/sda6 boot
mount --bind /dev dev
mount --bind /proc proc
mount --bind /sys sys
chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub2
```

This will make the job what standart installer fails for some reason. The advantage of this method is that you don't have to install any third-party packages.

Comment: I am having this error:
Path `/boot/grub` is not readable by Grub on boot. Installation ins impossible. Aborting

Comment: @black, is your boot settings branch located on another partition than Ubuntu? Then you have to do some preparations. I'll edit my answer to make it more helpful in thes situation.