# cannot boot Ubuntu 13.04 64bit (dualboot Windows-8)

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, laptop, windows-8, asus

I was have Ubuntu before maybe 10.10 and was working fine. after I buy my new laptop AsusX401A with Win8-64bit, I was installed Ubuntu 13.04 but after restart the computer I got a black Screen. and I Google it and install boot-repair. and than, just I can log-on to Win8 only. If i boot Ubuntu I got this message.

[[ 2.238863 kernel panic - not syncing: no init found. try passing init= option to kernel. see linux Docmentation/init.txt for guidance. ]]

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/314945/dual-booting-windows-8-ubuntu-12-04-2-grub-doesnt-appear-and-machine-never-boo OR http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the following instructions to install a dual boot
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tired-of-windows-8-how-to-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu/